# POST to REST API from my ESP8266

Tags: api, post, arduino, esp8266

I've made a REST API and I'd like to do a post request to one of the endpoints from my ESP8266, but I can't manage to do so.

The code inside the loop so far:

```
HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient



http.begin("http://localhost:5000/api/users/5b1e82fb8c620238a85646fc/arduinos/5b243dc666c18a2e10eb4097/data");
   http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
   http.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjViMWU4MmZiOGM2MjAyMzhhODU2NDZmYyIsImlhdCI6MTUyOTEwMTc5MiwiZXhwIjoxNTI5MTE2MTkyfQ.2O6knqriuFoEW9C2JQKRlM3D0DNnzqC7e7gpidy3pWU");
http.end();
```

The problem is that I don't know how to set the body of the request.

It should be a json with a single key called "value". For instance:

```
{
"value":101
}
```

Anyone knows how to do it? Also it's probable that I should use the ip instead of "localhost".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which language is that?

Comment: C, for arduino. That's the code inside the loop block.

Comment: Thanks. Add a relevant tag please :) .

Comment: 1) If you are expecting json data, shouldn't the Content-Type be `application/json`? 2) you need to have something like `responseCode=http.POST(Request)` to send the post request, and then follow by `response=http:getString()` to get the response before you end the http connection.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the application/json. How should I write that Request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ArduinoJson` Library [here](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson). Then you can build your HTTP body.

```cpp
StaticJsonBuffer<300> JSONbuffer;   //Declaring static JSON buffer
JsonObject& JSONencoder = JSONbuffer.createObject();

JSONencoder["value"] = value_var;
char JSONmessageBuffer[300];
JSONencoder.prettyPrintTo(JSONmessageBuffer, sizeof(JSONmessageBuffer));

HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient

http.begin("API end point here");      //Specify request destination
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  //Specify content-type header

int httpCode = http.POST(JSONmessageBuffer);   //Send the request
String payload = http.getString();                  //Get the response payload
```

Then use the above sample code to encapsulate JSON and send it to the API endpoint.

Comment: Flawless Sandun. Thanks!